# How to unit test generated promise chain

Tags: javascript, promise, mocha.js, sinon

I have a upload module that uploads an array of files serially. An upload should only be started after previous upload has completed.

A promise chain is constructed to achieve this:

```
let chain = Promise.resolve();

files.forEach(file => {
  chain = chain.then(() => upload(file)); // upload returns a promise
});

chain.then(() => console.log('Files uploaded'));
```

I want to make sure that this chain executes `upload()` back-to-back. How can I test it?

Comment: By the definition and proper implementation of promises, it will call the first `upload()` and not call it again until the first one resolves.  That's how promises work. So, unless you're trying to test promises, it seems like what you really kneed to know is whether `upload()` doesn't resolve until the upload is actually finished. You can't do that from a black box outside. You'd have to either have some data from the server to verify that only one upload was coming from a given source at a time or you'd have to write some tests of the upload function itself to test various conditions, etc...

Comment: @jfriend00 I think the benefit of testing this chain is it is out of the spec of promise. The implementation above is actually quite fragile. If one didn't wrap the `upload()` function in another function, or forgot to return the promise, all uploads will be executed in parallel. So I think it still worth the effort to test the chain generation. I think try to stub the `upload()` function to make sure it is completed before another one is called. Thanks!

Comment: The point is the issue is entirely in the implementation of `upload()`.  Feel free to test everything else if you want, but it's the implementation of `upload()` that determines whether this works or not and you will have to be able to see exactly what it does (on the server) in order to test what you've asked.

Comment: @jfriend00 Lets say `upload()` simply returns `Promise.resolve()`. How can I make sure that `upload()` is being called one-by-one instead of being fired all at once?

Comment: You'd have to put an actual async operation in `upload()` to tell if another one was being started before the former one completed.  If it's synchronous with just return `Promise.resolve()` in it, then nothing else can happen while it's executing.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ahh I see the point. Ok I will try to stub `upload()` with timeout and see how it goes

Answer (score 0):

return the chain from your test, mocha will wait for promises to resolve. You might want to jack in some sort of spy to count the number of invocations, that can be expected in the then() of your complete chain afterwards. You also need to return the upload in your then handler, to let the chain wait for promise to resolve before invoking the next step.

```
it('test chain', function () {
  let chain = Promise.resolve();

  files.forEach(file => {
    chain = chain.then(() => return upload(file)); // upload returns a promise
  });

  return chain.then(() => console.log('Files uploaded'));
}
```

Comment: Hmm.... but how do i know they are being executed one by one? Because parallel execution will results in the same invocation count too. By the way, arrow function without curly braces returns its body automatically. :)

Comment: Ah, yeah sorry, my bad about the arrow function, didn't look close enough. You could add an expect for each increment where you expect an incremental value, but perhaps that would be outside of your test code? It was not clear if your code snippet was the test or the actual implementation.

Comment: And maybe you should reconsider if that is a valid test to begin with, you would only test that promises work as intended, and that is an implementation detail which you might want to change in the future. The test should perhaps not fail if you chose to implement a parallell invokation instead, you want to make sure that all calls are made.

Comment: Ah sorry i forgot to mention that that is implementation code. Yes I think a test to make sure all calls are made is more important too. However, just out of curiosity, if one is writing a library to help generating promise chain, how can it be tested?

Comment: Well, in that case, you probably need to specifically test how that method is chaining the promises, by mocking the promise. Basically, you would test the functionality of your forEach loop, and check that the mocked promise is invoked like this: `promise.then().then().then() ...` and not `promise.then(); promise.then(); promise.then();`

Comment: Subsequently as jfriend00 says, you would also need a separate test to check that upload doesn't resolve until the underlying upload functionality is finished.